# How can I 'pop' an element from PyListObject?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cpython, python-c-api

Let’s say I have a `PyListObject`, and I want to append a `PyObject`. I can use the `PyList_Append` API which is documented in the [List Objects C-API](https://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/list.html?highlight=m#list-objects). But for my use case, I want to `pop` an element from the `PyListObject` (i.e., `my_list.pop()` in python layer).

But the *List Objects C-API* documentation does not have any hint about the `pop` operation.

How can I `pop` an element from `PyListObject` using C-API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `list.pop` method is not directly available via the C-API on `PyListObject`s.

Given that `list.pop` already exists and is implemented in C you could simply look up what the CPython implementation does:

```c
static PyObject *
list_pop_impl(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t index)
{
    PyObject *v;
    int status;

    if (Py_SIZE(self) == 0) {
        /* Special-case most common failure cause */
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "pop from empty list");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (index < 0)
        index += Py_SIZE(self);
    if (index < 0 || index >= Py_SIZE(self)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "pop index out of range");
        return NULL;
    }
    v = self->ob_item[index];
    if (index == Py_SIZE(self) - 1) {
        status = list_resize(self, Py_SIZE(self) - 1);
        if (status >= 0)
            return v; /* and v now owns the reference the list had */
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    Py_INCREF(v);
    status = list_ass_slice(self, index, index+1, (PyObject *)NULL);
    if (status < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(v);
        return NULL;
    }
    return v;
}
```

[Source for CPython 3.7.2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/listobject.c#L953-L997)

This includes a lot of functions that are not (easily) accessible for a C extension and it also handles popping from a specific index (even negative ones). Personally I wouldn't even bother to re-implement it but just call the `pop` method with [`PyObject_CallMethod`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod):

```c
PyObject *
list_pop(PyObject *lst){
    return PyObject_CallMethod(lst, "pop", "n", Py_SIZE(lst) - 1);
}
```

It might be a bit slower than a re-implementation but it should be "safer" - one cannot accidentally mess up invariants of the list object (for example resize conditions).

Another implementation is present in [Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/0.29.5/Cython/Utility/Optimize.c#L104-L111)

```c
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyList_Pop(PyObject* L) {
    /* Check that both the size is positive and no reallocation shrinking needs to be done. */
    if (likely(PyList_GET_SIZE(L) > (((PyListObject*)L)->allocated >> 1))) {
        Py_SIZE(L) -= 1;
        return PyList_GET_ITEM(L, PyList_GET_SIZE(L));
    }
    return CALL_UNBOUND_METHOD(PyList_Type, "pop", L);
}
```

That could also be adapted for your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to roll it out by yourself. Here is a possible implementation (without error checking):

```c
PyObject *my_pop_from_list(PyListObject *lst){
    //TODO: check lst isn't empty
    Py_SIZE(lst) -= 1;                                 // forget last element 
    return PyList_GET_ITEM(lst, PyList_GET_SIZE(lst)); // return last element
}
```

[`Py_SIZE`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_SIZE) is just a macro to access `lst->ob_size`, which we decrease while executing `pop`.

Also versions without error checking, i.e. `PyList_GET_ITEM` and `PyList_GET_SIZE`, are used, because once it is established (see TODO-comment), that the list isn't empty - nothing could go wrong.

The caller receives a new reference, albeit `PyList_GET_ITEM` returns a borrowed one: decreasing the size of the list the way we did in the code above, makes list "forget" the reference without decreasing the reference counter.

As @MSeifert has pointed out, this version doesn't change the size of the underlying array, the same way `list.pop()` would do (if only half or less of the underlying array is used after pop).  This could be seen as "feature" of the above implementation - trading speed for memory.

Comment: Note that this implementation won't resize the lists internal array what the actual `list.pop` implementation does. This might lead to needing more memory than necessary.